# How to adjust image for the button?

Tags: android, image

I have used background image for the button but the image is stretched and its looking odd. So can anyone help me what I can do? 
My xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="2" android:background="@drawable/board" >
  <ScrollView android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView1">
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1" > 

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView android:text="1" android:textSize="30dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imag1" android:src="@drawable/w10"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"> </ImageView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/no1" android:text="1" android:textSize="60dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView android:text="2" android:textSize="30dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imag1" android:src="@drawable/w10"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"> </ImageView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/no2" android:text="2" android:textSize="60dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView android:text="3" android:textSize="30dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imag1" android:src="@drawable/w10"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"> </ImageView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/no3" android:text="3" android:textSize="60dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>
<Button android:id="@+id/practice" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/practice" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/home" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/home" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="onClick"></Button>
```

and my Java file is:

```
package com.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Numbers extends Activity {

    TextView[] txt = new TextView[20];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.no);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(), "fonts/brhknd.ttf");

        for(int i = 0; i<mBtn.length; i++ )
        {
        txt[i] = (TextView)findViewById(mBtn[i]);
        txt[i].setTypeface(tf);

        }
        Button btnPractice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.practice);
        btnPractice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Numbers.this,DrawingNumber.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        Button btnHome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home);
        btnHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Numbers.this,mainClass.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    int[] mBtn = {R.id.no1,R.id.no2,R.id.no3,R.id.no4,R.id.no5,R.id.no6,R.id.no7,R.id.no8,R.id.no9,R.id.no10};


}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you set the dimensions of the button to match image?

Answer (score 2):

Use nine-patch resource.

[Nine-Patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch)

[StateList](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Comment: But I have Four buttons in a layout at the bottom.They are Previous,Practice,Home and then Next.

Comment: And? Read the document firstly.\

Comment: Yes.I want to make it as click able too.